# Отличие VPN от Garena, Hamachi, Tunngle

Tags: сеть

Доброго времени суток!
Объясните, пожалуйста, чем отличается обычная сеть VPN от программ Garena, Hamachi, Tunngle и иже подобных?
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Ничем. Hamachi, Tunngle и Gardena по сути просто предоставляют свой VPN сервер и клиентскую часть. А вообще вопрос на другой форум.

Answer (score 1):

Garena, Hamachi, Tunngle - программу, которые сами создают VPN-туннель. Условно говоря, UI-интерфейс для создания туннелей.